# Is "of that" a relative phrase？

Tags: relative-clauses

> 1. Success adores the prosperous attitude, of **that** you can be sure.

I think there is a problem in this sentence: if the last half  is a relative clause "which" should be used instead:

> 2. Success adores the prosperous attitude, of **which** you can be sure.

Or I can split it into two sentences:

> 3.Success adores the prosperous attitude. Of **that** you can be sure.

There is a variant of it where "of that" is in its original position:

> 3a. Success adores the prosperous attitude. You can be sure of **that** .

Or using a semicolon

> 4. Success adores the prosperous attitude; of **that** you can be sure.

Am i correct？

The context is shown in the picture below.

[image: . p]

Comment: What is it that one may be sure of? The attitude or the fact that Success adores it?

Comment: I don't think ***of that*** really means anything at all in the cited context, since nothing changes if it's omitted. In principle ***of that*** is a prepositional adjectival/adverbial phrase providing more information about the adjective ***sure.*** Specifically, "sure of the thing just said", not "sure of yourself" or whatever. But that's contextually obvious anyway, which is why ***of that*** is "unnecessary".

Comment: No: relative phrases are only of the _wh_ type, as in "from which", "to which" and "in which".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am guessing "the fact"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a relative clause; it doesn't supply more information about either noun. It's just an assertion that the first clause is true.

Comment: Do you think the original form is correct? If the last half isn't a relative clause,  then the whole sentence is run-on sentence, I think. So in the place of the comma, the author should have used a full stop or a semicolon.

Comment: I googled "of that you can be sure" and found several examples where it follows a comma. I can't give you an 'official' reason why it's acceptable in this case; it just is.

Comment: Thanks,  My concern is that it could be a typographic oversight.  As long as a native speaker thinks it is fine,  I'll just remember it.

Answer (score 1):

No: "that" is a determiner functioning as a fused determiner-head in NP structure.

Relative phrases are only of the *wh* type.

Note in any case that relative "that" is a subordinator, not a relative pronoun.

If you replace "of that" with "of which", then you would have a relative phrase where "which" refers to "prosperous attitude".

Comment: And does the same analysis  hold if the sentence were *Success adores the prosperous attitude—you can be sure of that.* ?

Comment: How do you analyze the original sentence?  If the last half isn't a relative clause,  the whole sentence is the run-on one.

Comment: @ForOU It would be preferable to use a stronger punctuation mark such as a semi-colon or a dash.

Answer (score 0):

Success adores the prosperous attitude, of that you can be sure.

is **post-positioning**. "of that" is accurate as it is anaphoric or refers back to the main idea.

**You can be sure of success adoring the prosperous attitude.**

It is fine the way it is and just emphasizes the success bit. You being sure it less important to the writer.

This is allowable because we say: **to be sure of something**.

"which" is OK too but less emphatic.

Comment: If the last half isn't a relative clause,  then the whole sentence is run-on sentence, I think. So in the place of the comma, the author should have used a full stop or a semicolon.

Comment: @ForOU A relative clause does not start with "**of that**. He was sure of that. Not a relative clause.